# nodata triggers are continuously in p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m state in Zabbix 3.2

Tags: zabbix

I'm upgrading Zabbix from 2.2 to 3.2 at the moment. In 3.2 i'm a bit surprised with the behaviour of nodata triggers because they are in PROBLEM state every time. It doesn't generate events, but when you go the triggers section it appears as one of the problems of the host.

The trigger is configured to detect when command agent.ping doesn't deliver any value to Zabbix Server. The value "1" is received every minute without troubles. The trigger is configured to consider PROBLEM whether value is not receive in 5 minutes.

```
{HOST:agent.ping.nodata(300)}=1
```

Could it be a bug or is it the normal operation way in Zabbix 3.2.1?

Answer (score 2):

From [Zabbix manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions):

> Starting from Zabbix 3.2, nodata(), date(), dayofmonth(), dayofweek(),
>   now() and time() functions are calculated for unsupported items, too.
>   Other functions require that the referenced item is in a supported
>   state.

So it is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same behavior on our Zabbix server 3.2.1.

The host and agent were unavailable for a few minutes (reboot), every trigger came back to normal except:
Template App Zabbix Agent:agent.ping.nodata

The only solution I found so far, was to unlink and clear the template from host. And add the template again.
The trigger state came back to normal.

Could this be an issue ? Never had this behavior on previous versions of Zabbix.